# Google Cloud (Direct) Incoming SMTP

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp, email-attachments, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have an AppEngine that receives automatic data via email from remote sites and stores it into the datastore.  We're using a 3rd Party SMTP host now, and /_ah/mail/ is working properly.

A lot of this data is coming from legacy microcontrollers, PLCs, smart meters and the like.  They all have a configuration for email address, SMTP server, SMTP user/pass, From address, and interval.

We'd like to setup postfix on a g1-small Compute Engine instance to handle authenticated direct-SMTP connections for the incoming data, but there are no examples of anyone else doing this.  Is it as simple as writing a postfix filter to take the data and POST it over to /_ah/mail on AppEngine?

Alternately, is there an easier way that we're missing?  We are converting some of the devices to use POST/PUT where possible, but we have a lot of different devices, and that will take time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App Engine provides an SMTP service for inbound email - messages sent to `<anything>@<app_id>.appspotmail.com` will be sent to `/_ah/mail/<anything>`. If your devices only need to send email into your system you could point them directly to [GAE's mail servers](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3ayour_project.appspotmail.com&run=toolpage).

Your suggestion of running a inbound mailserver on GCE and using it to forward to HTTP on your app is also a viable solution, and doesn't require abusing email servers. [There are even companies that will do this for you](http://mailnuggets.com/)!

Comment: My only concerns about using the GAE mail servers directly is I don't want it to look like spam and start blocking/bouncing the messages.

Certainly worth testing, though.

Comment: @ccrvincent can you explain how spam/block/bounce is a concern on incoming mail? Outgoing I understand but I can't see how that plays into this scenario. Thanks for humoring me.

Comment: I am not / was not sure if Google applied any anti-spam methods to messages received through appspotmail.  Attempting to direct-send would likely trip off some of those (lack of SPF, coming from dynamic IP ranges, etc.)

We ended up just using SendGrid as a SMTP host.  Then we can configure SPF and have a little redundancy.

Comment: How would one stop others from sending email to <anything>@<app_id>.appspotmail.com? Perhaps the app could get spammed with unwanted emails. A third party or private smtp server could be the first target of the emails from the PLCs etc. This smtp server could drop messages that do not arrive from approved senders and forward the rest to the GAE app address. This can sometimes become necessary to avoid getting flooded by useless traffic to the GAE app.